# Wifi stopped working after cable connection on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, dual-boot, wireless, atheros

I have owned a Ubuntu 14.04 machine for five years now. Lately, I moved my residence and had to connect by ethernet for a while. Then, suddenly Ubuntu cannot recognize any network. Note that **this machine has a dual boot with Windows and Wifi in Windows is working fine**.

The aim of my question is to find what is the problem. I will post any information that is needed to figure out what may be the question. I myself have tried so many guides that now I don't know where to start from.

Here is the output of the command to gather information about my system:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 11 Nov 2018 14:24 CET +0100

Booted last: 11 Nov 2018 14:04 CET +0100

Script from: 22 Oct 2018 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.4.0-138-generic #164~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 5 08:56:16 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc Device [11ad:0612]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k

03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8172 Fast Ethernet [1969:10a0] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems Device [1179:fa30]
    Kernel driver in use: alx

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b3b1 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 058f:6366 Alcor Micro Corp. Multi Flash Reader
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 0930:0220 Toshiba Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: Toshiba Bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

'mokutil' is not installed (package "mokutil").

##### lsmod #############################

ath3k                  20480  0 
bluetooth             520192  26 bnep,ath3k,btbcm,btrtl,btusb,rfcomm,btintel
ath9k                 143360  0 
ath9k_common           36864  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              479232  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
toshiba_wmi            16384  0 
ath                    32768  3 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_hw
mac80211              733184  1 ath9k
cfg80211              561152  4 ath,ath9k_common,ath9k,mac80211
sparse_keymap          16384  2 toshiba_wmi,toshiba_acpi
wmi                    20480  2 toshiba_wmi,toshiba_acpi

##### interfaces ########################

[/etc/network/interfaces]
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'eth0' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 192.168.1.109/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fd22:eaf3:5c5c::f79/128 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fd22:eaf3:5c5c:0:4d68:3a21:f149:5aa0/64 scope global temporary dynamic 
       valid_lft 604125sec preferred_lft 85125sec
    inet6 fd22:eaf3:5c5c:0:<IP6 'eth0' [IF1]>/64 scope global dynamic 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::<IP6 'eth0' [IF1]>/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]> brd <MAC address>

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off


##### route #############################

default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0  proto static 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.109  metric 1 

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root ‘/etc/resolv.conf’ -> ‘../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf’]
nameserver 127.0.1.1
search lan

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root      4468     1  0 14:13 ?        00:00:00 NetworkManager

##### NetworkManager info ###############

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: <MAC address> ----------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Bluetooth
  Driver:            bluez
  State:             disconnected
  Default:           no

  Capabilities:

- Device: eth0  [Cableada automática] -----------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            alx
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC 'eth0' [IF1]>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           100 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.1.109
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.1.1

    DNS:             192.168.1.1

  IPv6 Settings:
    Address:         fd22:eaf3:5c5c::f79
    Prefix:          128
    Gateway:         ::

    Address:         fd22:eaf3:5c5c:0:4d68:3a21:f149:5aa0
    Prefix:          64
    Gateway:         ::

    Address:         fd22:eaf3:5c5c:0:<IP6 'eth0' [IF1]>
    Prefix:          64
    Gateway:         ::

    Address:         fe80::<IP6 'eth0' [IF1]>
    Prefix:          64
    Gateway:         ::

    DNS:             fd22:eaf3:5c5c::1

- Device: wlan0 ----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            ath9k
  State:             unmanaged
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>

  Capabilities:

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points 

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq
no-auto-default=<MAC 'eth0' [IF1]>,
[ifupdown]
managed=true
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=mac:<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/MASMOVIL_jywa]] (600 root)
[connection] id=MASMOVIL_jywa | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=MASMOVIL_jywa | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/claudia~]] (600 root)
[connection] id=claudia | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=claudia | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/EXE_WIFI]] (600 root)
[connection] id=EXE_WIFI | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=EXE_WIFI | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Senderos]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Senderos | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Senderos | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Sunrise_2.4GHz_3C9B50]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Sunrise_2.4GHz_3C9B50 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Sunrise_2.4GHz_3C9B50 | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Swisscom]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Swisscom | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Swisscom | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/MOVISTAR_D810]] (600 root)
[connection] id=MOVISTAR_D810 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=MOVISTAR_D810 | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Telekom]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Telekom | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Telekom | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/JAZZTEL_Jzng]] (600 root)
[connection] id=JAZZTEL_Jzng | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=JAZZTEL_Jzng | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Airport_Free_WiFi_AENA]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Airport_Free_WiFi_AENA | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Airport_Free_WiFi_AENA | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Conexion]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Conexion | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=LARA-WIFI
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/case Wifi(ssid: String) =>]] (600 root)
[connection] id=case Wifi(ssid: String) => | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=case Wifi(ssid: String) => | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/kubi]] (600 root)
[connection] id=kubi | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=kubi | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/public-epfl]] (600 root)
[connection] id=public-epfl | type=802-11-wireless | autoconnect=false
[802-11-wireless] ssid=public-epfl | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/GSGWIFI]] (600 root)
[connection] id=GSGWIFI | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=GSGWIFI | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/MOVISTAR_5640]] (600 root)
[connection] id=MOVISTAR_5640 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=MOVISTAR_5640 | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/IML ]] (600 root)
[connection] id=IML  | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=IML  | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/_AUTO_ONOWiFi]] (600 root)
[ipv6] method=auto
[connection] id=_AUTO_ONOWiFi | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=_AUTO_ONOWiFi | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/WIFIALSA]] (600 root)
[connection] id=WIFIALSA | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=WIFIALSA | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/DOMO]] (600 root)
[connection] id=DOMO | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=DOMO | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/CITEU-Residents]] (600 root)
[connection] id=CITEU-Residents | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=CITEU-Residents | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/JIMA2]] (600 root)
[connection] id=JIMA2 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=JIMA2 | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Mismenet - Jose]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Mismenet - Jose | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Mismenet - Jose | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/grus]] (600 root)
[connection] id=grus | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=grus | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/MASMOVIL_DHgM]] (600 root)
[connection] id=MASMOVIL_DHgM | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=MASMOVIL_DHgM | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/CITEU-Visitors]] (600 root)
[connection] id=CITEU-Visitors | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=CITEU-Visitors | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Orange-0dc8]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Orange-0dc8 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Orange-0dc8 | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Sunrise_2.4GHz_27D400]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Sunrise_2.4GHz_27D400 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=Sunrise_2.4GHz_27D400 | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/epfl]] (600 root)
[ipv6] method=auto
[connection] id=epfl | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=epfl | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
[802-1x] ca-cert=/etc/ssl/certs/thawte_Primary_Root_CA.pem
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/freewifi-epfl]] (600 root)
[connection] id=freewifi-epfl | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=freewifi-epfl | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/MONZOON]] (600 root)
[connection] id=MONZOON | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=MONZOON | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/MOVISTAR_83D0]] (600 root)
[connection] id=MOVISTAR_83D0 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=MOVISTAR_83D0 | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/MOVISTAR_2A76]] (600 root)
[connection] id=MOVISTAR_2A76 | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=MOVISTAR_2A76 | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ALSA PREMIUM]] (600 root)
[connection] id=ALSA PREMIUM | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=ALSA PREMIUM | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/claudia]] (600 root)
[connection] id=claudia | type=802-11-wireless
[802-11-wireless] ssid=claudia | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/cviugr]] (600 root)
[connection] id=cviugr | type=802-11-wireless | permissions=user:usuario:; | autoconnect=false
[802-11-wireless] ssid=cviugr | mac-address=<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
[ipv6] method=auto
[ipv4] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/eduroam]] (600 root)
[connection] id=eduroam | type=802-11-wireless | permissions=user:usuario:; | autoconnect=false
[802-11-wireless] ssid=eduroam
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto
[802-1x] ca-cert=/home/usuario/.cat_installer/ca.pem

##### Netplan config ####################

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/Madrid (based on set time zone)

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (3, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (3, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5735 - 5835 @ 40), (3, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

eth0      no frequency information.

wlan0     13 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Channel 12 : 2.467 GHz
          Channel 13 : 2.472 GHz

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

wlan0     Interface doesn't support scanning : Network is down

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[ath3k]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-138-generic/kernel/drivers/bluetooth/ath3k.ko
firmware:       ath3k-1.fw
license:        GPL
version:        1.0
description:    Atheros AR30xx firmware driver
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     AC2C693C639F7A0981097A7
depends:        bluetooth
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-138-generic SMP mod_unload modversions retpoline 

[ath9k]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-138-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Support for Atheros 802.11n wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     D578DE67B7E1EB3760B717B
depends:        mac80211,ath9k_hw,ath9k_common,cfg80211,ath
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-138-generic SMP mod_unload modversions retpoline 
parm:           debug:Debugging mask (uint)
parm:           nohwcrypt:Disable hardware encryption (int)
parm:           blink:Enable LED blink on activity (int)
parm:           led_active_high:Invert LED polarity (int)
parm:           btcoex_enable:Enable wifi-BT coexistence (int)
parm:           bt_ant_diversity:Enable WLAN/BT RX antenna diversity (int)
parm:           ps_enable:Enable WLAN PowerSave (int)
parm:           use_chanctx:Enable channel context for concurrency (int)

[ath9k_common]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-138-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_common.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Shared library for Atheros wireless 802.11n LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     5E13CACC8C4252BB4B57367
depends:        ath9k_hw,cfg80211,ath
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-138-generic SMP mod_unload modversions retpoline 

[ath9k_hw]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-138-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath9k/ath9k_hw.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Support for Atheros 802.11n wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     0ABA5B381F76029EC68B97E
depends:        ath
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-138-generic SMP mod_unload modversions retpoline 

[ath]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-138-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Shared library for Atheros wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     45AB6427635D8FAD0CF48E6
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-138-generic SMP mod_unload modversions retpoline 

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-138-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     12876CD014B88DBC2461E53
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-138-generic SMP mod_unload modversions retpoline 
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.0-138-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     512570CCFE6B901E551DC5B
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.0-138-generic SMP mod_unload modversions retpoline 
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[ath9k]
blink: 0
bt_ant_diversity: 0
btcoex_enable: 0
led_active_high: -1
nohwcrypt: 0
ps_enable: 0
use_chanctx: 0

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp
rtc

coretemp
ath9k

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/hp.conf]
blacklist hp_wmi

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

[/etc/modprobe.d/modesetting.conf]
options cirrus modeset=1
options mgag200 modeset=1

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x1969:0x10a0 (alx)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF1]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
# PCI device 0x168c:0x0036 (ath9k)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan0"
# USB device 0x:0x (mt7601u)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="wlan*", NAME="wlan1"

##### dmesg #############################

[   28.540944] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[  159.595944] alx 0000:03:00.0 eth0: NIC Up: 100 Mbps Full
[  159.596579] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[  292.372371] alx 0000:03:00.0 eth0: Link Down
[  377.201912] alx 0000:03:00.0 eth0: NIC Up: 100 Mbps Full
[  481.160781] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[  481.161586] alx 0000:03:00.0 eth0: NIC Up: 100 Mbps Full
[  481.161858] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
[  564.297741] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[  564.298560] alx 0000:03:00.0 eth0: NIC Up: 100 Mbps Full
[  564.298831] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############




  [1]: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-troubleshooting-hardware-check.html.en
  [2]: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessCardsSupported
```

Comment: I have no solution for the moment but a suggestion: Starting think and preparing for a release upgrade. 14.04 has only a few months left of support. Upgrading to 16.04 most likely will reinstall newer drivers and make iot work again.

Comment: Did you make changes to /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf

Comment: @Jeremy31 probably while following some tutorial. do you need the contents of the file?

Comment: It is in the script results, not the default anymore

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We see this in your scan results:

> wlan0     Interface doesn't support scanning : Network is down

It is probably because of this in /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq
no-auto-default=<MAC 'eth0' [IF1]>,
[ifupdown]
managed=true
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=mac:<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
```

In other words, you have asked that Network Manager *not* manage the wireless. Let's make a backup of the relevent file and then amend it. From the terminal:

```
sudo cp /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf ~/NetworkManager.conf.old
sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

Remove these lines entirely:

```
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=mac:<MAC 'wlan0' [IF2]>
```

**NOTE**: The wireless script from which the diagnostics report that you posted comes from is designed for security reasons to redact MAC addresses. Therefore, your actual lines will have the actual MAC address in place of the redacted version above. Whatever it reads, remove it.

Proofread carefully, save and close nano. Restart Network Manager:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

It may take a reboot.